Error to estimate prediction interval in glmm with gamma family
I gathered 3 studies on healthy subjects assessing same biological parameter y.
y is a positive bounded parameter. His distribution follows a gamma distribution.
I have a model glmm wth gamma family
glmm1<-glmer(y~SEX+(1|STUDY), data=mydata, family = Gamma).

SEX is factor with 2 levels : male - female
enter image description here
I have a significant sex effect, and and i would to estimate reference values of y according to SEX by estimating prediction interval from the model glmm1.
i used ggeffects with predict_response function.
predict_response(glmm1, terms = c("SEX"), type = "random", interval = "prediction")
plot(predict_response(glmm1, terms = c("SEX"), type = "random", interval = "prediction"))

enter image description here
enter image description here
As you can see, the results are aberrant concerning prediction interval. Indeed, prediction interval do not contain mean.
How could i estimate correctly prediction interval for my glmm model with gamma family ?

First, actually, the lower and upper intervals are swapped for models with inverse link (i.e., lower CI is actually upper CI and vice versa), however, this will be fixed in this PR.
Second, the prediction interval does not yet work for models with inverse-link. I'm not sure how to transform the returned dispersion/sigma parameter that is required for the prediction interval . The scaling is not aligned.
You could, however, calculate adjusted predictions based on simulated draws (type = "simulate"), which is close to (or even better than?) prediction intervals:
library(ggeffects)
set.seed(123)
warpbreaks$ID <- sample(1:5, nrow(warpbreaks), replace = TRUE)

m1 <- suppressWarnings(glmmTMB::glmmTMB(
  breaks ~ wool * tension + (1 | ID),
  family = Gamma(),
  data = warpbreaks
))

# confidence intervals
predict_response(m1, c("wool", "tension"))
#> # Predicted values of breaks
#> 
#> tension: L
#> 
#> wool | Predicted |       95% CI
#> -------------------------------
#> A    |     44.63 | 57.87, 36.32
#> B    |     28.16 | 36.36, 22.98
#> 
#> tension: M
#> 
#> wool | Predicted |       95% CI
#> -------------------------------
#> A    |     23.99 | 30.94, 19.59
#> B    |     28.58 | 37.65, 23.04
#> 
#> tension: H
#> 
#> wool | Predicted |       95% CI
#> -------------------------------
#> A    |     24.61 | 31.78, 20.07
#> B    |     18.81 | 24.29, 15.35
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * ID = NA (population-level)

# simulated draws
predict_response(m1, c("wool", "tension"), type = "simulate")
#> # Predicted values of breaks
#> 
#> tension: L
#> 
#> wool | Predicted |       95% CI
#> -------------------------------
#> A    |     44.79 | 20.00, 80.46
#> B    |     28.12 | 12.65, 50.02
#> 
#> tension: M
#> 
#> wool | Predicted |       95% CI
#> -------------------------------
#> A    |     24.04 | 10.62, 42.66
#> B    |     28.51 | 12.78, 50.75
#> 
#> tension: H
#> 
#> wool | Predicted |       95% CI
#> -------------------------------
#> A    |     24.70 | 11.33, 43.16
#> B    |     18.78 |  8.28, 33.16

Confidence intervals

simulated draws

Created on 2024-08-30 with reprex v2.1.1
